# optimize sql multiple left join and where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT distinct text FROM oc_product_attribute as pa
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category as ptc ON  pa.product_id = ptc.product_id
LEFT JOIN oc_product as p ON pa.product_id = ptc.product_id
WHERE p.status = 1 AND ptc.category_id = 61 
GROUP BY pa.text LIMIT 10
```

My db hang for the above query although I use LIMIT. Any way to optimize it?

Comment: use top 10 instead of limit.

Comment: Are you using indices on the columns you are joining?

Comment: @DH__ - isn't `TOP` the SQL Version of `LIMIT`?  This is MySQL.  Note that, unless `pa.text` is indexed (and the optimizer is smart enough/can take advantage of it), the DB has to get all the rows, order them, _then_ select the desired 10/throw everything else away.

Comment: Your WHERE clause changes both LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN, because of its condition that checks fields of LEFT JOINed tables. If this isn't your intention, move those conditions to the appropriate `ON` clause. Furthermore you should use EXPLAIN <your query> and post the result here together with the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE <your tables>

Comment: Why are you using `DISTINCT text` and using `GROUP BY pa.text` . Both are trying to do the same thing here. What data type is the text column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line you shoud use the alias `p` instead of `ptc`

```
LEFT JOIN oc_product as p ON pa.product_id = ptc.product_id
```

shold be

```
LEFT JOIN oc_product as p ON pa.product_id = p.product_id
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain _why_ this is causing his statement to hang?

Comment: that is not possible according to my db design

Comment: What means "is not possible"? At the moment you build a cross product means you join every record from your first join with oc_product. That generates  more lines you would like to have. Add the create statements of your tables please.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that both the `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` is not needed in this query because you are anyway using both tables in the where clause. Also because you are just selecting the text column. You might consider rewriting the query to this:

```
SELECT 
    pa.text 
FROM 
    oc_product_attribute as pa
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        oc_product_to_category as ptc 
        JOIN oc_product as p 
            ON p.product_id = ptc.product_id
    WHERE  
        pa.product_id = ptc.product_id
        AND p.status = 1 
        AND ptc.category_id = 61
)
LIMIT 10
```